# XPath Select values with no "isNull"

Tags: xml, xpath

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <rows>
      <row>
         <c n="ColorName">Cyan</c>
         <c isNull="1" n="ColorType"/>
         <c isNull="1" n="ColorBook"/>
         <c isNull="1" n="SpotFunction"/>
         <c n="Angle">45.0</c>
      </row>
      <row>
         <c n="ColorName">HG8-Black</c>
         <c isNull="1" n="ColorType"/>
         <c n="ColorBook">designer</c>
         <c n="SpotFunction">RY</c>
         <c n="Angle">45.0</c>
      </row>
   </rows>
```

I have this structure and I need to get some values with this XPath:

```
/rows/row/c[3]/text()
```

My problem is that sometimes I have this `isNull="1"` attribute and I get an error because there is no value. It is possible to ignore the line when there is no value?

Comment: Better describe expected output .   
Please, read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

Try below to avoid matching `c` nodes with `isNull` attribute:

```
/rows/row/c[3][not(@isNull)]/text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this XPath expression :

```
/rows/row/c[3][@isNull]/text()
```